# How to get the friends contact infromation from android facebook sdk?

Tags: android

I have integrated the facebook sdk in my mobile and I could login and logout the app.
And also got the friend's first name,last name,location,etc..
But i couldn't get friend's contact information like email and mobile number 
So how can i get the information?

Answer (score 0):

Before listing any possible solution / suggestion, I would like to point out that the Facebook SDK / API **does not** expose a user's Phone Number (whether Mobile or otherwise) to any API calls. To the extent that you cannot access your **own** contact numbers using any API call.

FQL Method: [Reference Link - FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user)

Query the Facebook API using this query:

```
select email from user where uid = USER_ID_BEING_QUERIED
```

Graph API Method: [Reference Link - Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

```
USER_ID_BEING_QUERIED?fields=email&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

**Note:** The result of any of the queries above depends on the user sharing their email address / addresses with the current logged in user. If they are not sharing it with you, any of the above queries will not give you any result and will return an empty data set.

Comment: Can we get Phone numbers with same method??

Comment: @atasoyh: Nope. As mentioned at the start of the post, the API does not provide access to Phone numbers. Try it in the Graph Explorer.